# WiFi is constantly switching between very low and high speeds

Tags: networking, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Gnome flashback front end. Everything works except WiFi. This has been the case since 16.04 and is the same on a trial install of 20.04. The problem is there on a new Dell laptop, an Acer laptop, an Asus laptop, a very old Acer laptop, and a Dell 860 server.

The speed on startup is quite slow, and I suspect it's due to the as yet unsolved 'Failed to start Raise network interfaces' (for which 'systemctl status networking.service' provides only limited information). At this point WiFi is dropping from high speed to low speed and back again randomly. I wait until everything has had time to settle (usually about a minute) and then issue 'nmcli device disconnect wlp0s20f3' followed by 'nmcli connection up xxxxxx-yyyyyy'. The speed then comes up to 866Mb/s. I've given up on a fix for this.

From then on the speed randomly fluctuates between 866Mb/s and 6Mb/s.

I've turned off power management, turned off IPv6, disabled 802.11n, and anything else I've come across, reverting changes afterwards, that looks appropriate. In the Dell I've even changed the wireless card from an Atheros QCNFA435 to an Intel Wireless-AC 9560 with no change in the random fluctuations between 866Mb/s and 6Mb/s.

I've been putting up with it for four years now (along with problems with Flashback/Nemo, but that's another story) but it's come to a head with the increased use of Teams/Zoom/Skype/etc due to CoV-19, most notably when I'm presenting to in excess of 100 people on Teams. The low speed brings things to a halt, only recovered anything up to ten seconds later when it switches to high speed.

Has anyone any thoughts about this?

Comment: Nothing beats a good hardwired connection when it comes to bandwidth issues.  Way too many things can interfere with WiFi whether it's the 2.4GHz or the 5GHz range.  Most of the issues I have ever stumbled across are not separated bands on routers where the 2.4GHz and the 5GHz share names (SSIDs) which can cause confusion with the device that is connecting to it.  Also, messing around with channels like 1-11 for 2.4GHz, and many channels for the 5GHz may help.  Also, I have seen the "width" in the wireless setting cause issues.  Generally 40MHz for 5GHz and 20MHz for 2.4GHz should be good.

Comment: Unfortunately my issue is with WiFi, specifically the problem described which I have had since 16.04 only on my Ubuntu machines. A few my most used Ubuntu machines are dual boot with Windows (the oldest with XP and the newest with 10) as there are some programmes that don't run natively in Ubuntu nor with WINE nor a VirtualBox machine, so on the same hardware I have an instant comparison. I get no WiFi issues at all on any of my devices running Windows, or any other operating system. I have had an Ubuntu laptop running alongside a Windows laptop and seen the problem on one and not the other.

Comment: Can I ask why you disabled 802.11n?  N is what does the fastest speeds in the 2.4GHz range, and probably way more stable than 5GHz.  N can do up to 450Mbps per channel that's why you seen routers that are AC1900  1Gbps AC (5GHz) and 2x450Mbps (2.4GHz).  Also, have you at least made sure that the signal coming from the router is split into separate names for the 2.4GHz and 5GHz?  Maybe Windows might be able to handle combined names better than Linux can.

Comment: My adapter is a modern one which does 802.11ac. Not n. It has also been very standard to disable n to improve speed in Ubuntu for some years now if you are limited to just 2.4GHz. Fortunately I have 5GHz. These days 5GHz is at least as stable as 2.4GHz, especially with ax adapters. I do, of course, have different names for 2.4 and 5GHz. I have the channels set to the most appropriate ones for my locality and the bandwith set to the highest. But thank you for your suggestions.